# Make field required if entity reference field is filled

Tags: 8, forms, blocks

I'm trying to make some fields required if an entity reference field is filled.

This is the code I currently have:

```
$form['node'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#title' => $this->t('Node'),
  '#target_type' => 'node',
  '#default_value' => $node ?? '',
];

$form['image'] = [
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => $this->t('Image'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Override the node\'s image.'),
  '#upload_validators' => [
    'file_validate_extensions' => ['gif png jpg jpeg'],
    'file_validate_size' => [25600000],
  ],
  '#theme' => 'image_widget',
  '#preview_image_style' => 'medium',
  '#upload_location' => 'public://hero-images',
  '#default_value' => $config['image'] ?? '',
  '#states' => [
    'required' => [
      ':input[name="node"]' => ['filled' => TRUE],
    ],
  ],
];
```

It doesn't seem like this line `':input[name="node"]' => ['filled' => TRUE],` has any effect on the entity_autocomplete field.

Is is possible to do like this with entity_autocomplete fields?

The code is in a block configuration form.

Comment: Or could it be the other way and the required'ness isn't working on your image_widget? Might be worth changing it to make it do visible or something to rule that out

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that, that is the same problem.

Comment: The form state API is javascript based, so you have to check for the exact input name as given in the HTML source. And if I remember correctly, ER fields store their values usually in something like `[:input[name="field_node[target_id]"]` or `[:input[name="field_node[DELTA][target_id]"]`, but this might vary greatly depending on the field widget.

Comment: Thank you for the help, after inspecting the field I found out that I should write `':input[name="settings[node]"]' => ['filled' => FALSE],`.